# R automatically converts dates to string when importing xlsx

Tags: r, qualtrics, readxl

I have an excel file with a column of date info. These are the dates that people took a survey, and are formatted like "1/20/2017  2:22:34 PM" as downloaded from Qualtrics.

But when I import this file to R using read_excel, each date automatically gets converted to a string like "43122.82".

Ultimately I want these dates to be Date types. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried using the `col_types` argument?

Comment: Anything else in that column that's not a date?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`qualtRics`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qualtRics/vignettes/qualtRics.html) package?  If you have API access on your Qualtrics account, you can circumvent this issue by either loading data from Qualtrics into R directly.

Comment: Make your life easier and reformat the date column in Excel ! This should be a 1-click action.

Comment: using openxlsx::read.xlsx with detectDates argument

Answer (score 2):

You could either try using the `col_types` argument when reading the file, or do the conversion afterwards:

```
data$datecol <- as.Date(data$datecol, origin = "1900-01-01")
```

or if it's, as you say, a string...

```
data$datecol <- as.Date(as.numeric(data$datecol), origin = "1900-01-01")
```

Better even, to keep the time, try:

```
library(lubridate)
data$datecol <- as_datetime(as.numeric(data$datecol)*3600*24, origin='1900-01-01')
```

Comment: I think the origin should be '1899-12-30'. Excel has a bug of considering 29th Feb 1900 as a valid date, It was however invalid because it wasn't a leap year. I am also not very sure about it though. Thanks

Comment: Interesting... I also read somewhere that older versions of Excel use 1904-01-01 as a starting point... maybe not unrelated!

Comment: Joel Spolsky tells a great story about this: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/

Comment: @Aaron Nice! Everything is indeed interconnected.